# Visual Studio 2012 Profiler - DA0002 error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, profiler

I'm trying to use profiler but when i start this feature i got some chart of perfomance but all functions that are not from standard libraries are marked as [Unknown]. I suppouse it's related to the error that is shown:

```
DA0002: It appears that the file was collected without properly setting the environment variables with VSPerfCLREnv.cmd. Symbols for managed binaries may not resolve.
```

I googled for it and the only rational result was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385759.aspx but i dont get a thing about it.
Is there someone that have a clue what is it about and how to get rid of DA0002?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VS 2012 please install the updates. There is a known issue that was fixed where symbols do not resolve when running profiler on recent versions of windows